# Merge two points

Tags: modeling

[image]

How do you merge two points like the ones shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shortcut Alt + M to open the menu and select where you want to merge them like this:

[image]

Edit (2020): The shortcut has changed to M instead of Alt + M for anyone that finds this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Select both vertices and press Alt+M to merge, or W>remove doubles, to remove vertices which directly overlap.